Who introduced Maxwell's stress tensor?
The question might be obvious, but James Clerk Maxwell did not even use vectors for his equations. Oliver Heaviside was the one that wrote them in vector form. In a paper of from 1889 "On the Electromagnetic Effects due to the Motion of Electrification through a Dielectric" Heaviside already makes a reference to Maxwell's electric stress, citing "Electromagnetic Induction and its Propagation" 1886. (This last reference has a second half that is freely accessible from Google Books: https://books.google.fr/books?id=ZeoEAAAAYAAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s but I cannot find Maxwell stress tensor there.)
Is electric stress the same as the tensor? Who introduced Maxwell's stress tensor?

This is not an answer, but although Maxwell did not use vector notation, he did understand quaternions, and referred to part of the quaternion as the vector part and part of the quaternion as the scalar part, and used the terms "convergence", the negative of which we now know as "divergence", and also used the term "rotation" for what we now know as "curl" (rotation now usually refers to a line integral around a closed path, not the curl at a given point). So, although Maxwell didn't have the modern vector notation, he did have the concepts.

@MathKeepsMeBusy what would have been its equivalent of a tensor?
